# Seam Logger inside a Servlet?

Tags: java, logging, servlets, seam

Is there a way to use a Seam Logger inside of a standard Java Servlet?  I have one servlet that I use to serve up content, while the rest of my application is developed using Seam.  I'd like to be able to make use of Seam's built-in Log functionality in my servlet, the same way I do with the rest of my Seam-based classes.  In my Servlet constructor, I tried calling

```
Log logger = (Log)Component.getInstance(Log.class);
```

...but I'm getting an exception.  Is there a better way to "inject" a Logger into the servlet?  Something I'm missing?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't tested it, but you could try this :

```
Log mylog = Logging.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

That's what i use in my tests.

Comment: For me worked as `Log mylog = Logging.getLog(MyClass.class);`

Answer (score 3):

To use a Seam context you can wrap the `doPost` or `doGet` methods with `ContextualHttpServletRequest` which allows you to do Component lookups.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final HttpServletRequest req = request;
        new ContextualHttpServletRequest( req ) {
            public void process() throws Exception {
                wrappedPost( req );
            }
        }.run();
    }

// you renamed original doPost method
private void wrappedPost(HttpServletRequest request) {
...
}
```

The above example code allows you to access components by name, which are declared using the name annotation:

```
@Name("MyCcomponent")
```

The Logger is usually injected by the `@Logger` annotation, I checked logs the source package, there is no component with a `@Name` annotation that could be looked up. If you call a component (with @Logger) from the wrapped context, a logger will be injected (into the called compontent).

---

Seam uses in its components:

```
private static final LogProvider log = Logging
            .getLogProvider(MailSession.class);
```